# Overflow error in C code, Leetcode problem

Tags: c

I got a runtime error with my solution to İntersection of Two Arrays II  at leetcode.
I think my insertion sort causing overflow and the solution to the problem may be using pointers  with the sorting algorithm, but im not sure why i need to use pointers if thats the solution to my problem if not i still am not sure.

Error message:

```
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x603000000024 at pc 0x000000401ca7 bp 0x7ffe5b771ae0 sp 0x7ffe5b771ad0
READ of size 4 at 0x603000000024 thread T0
    #2 0x7f640600f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
0x603000000024 is located 0 bytes to the right of 20-byte region [0x603000000010,0x603000000024)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f640702af88 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10bf88)
    #3 0x7f640600f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c067fff8000: fa fa 00 00[04]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING
```

```
int* intersect(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size, int* returnSize){
int j,c;
    for(int i = 1; i < nums1Size; ++i){
        c = nums1[i];
        j = i - 1; 
        while(c < nums1[j] && j >= 0){
            nums1[j + 1] = nums1[j];
            --j;
        }
        nums1[j + 1] = c;
    }
    
    
    for(int i = 1; i < nums2Size; ++i){
        c = nums2[i]; 
        j = i - 1; 
        while(c < nums2[j] && j >= 0){
            nums2[j + 1] = nums2[j];
            --j;
        }
        nums2[j + 1] = c;
    }
    
    
    int z = 0,x = 0,y = 0;
    int low = (nums1Size > nums2Size) ?nums2Size :nums1Size;
    int* nums3  =  (int*)malloc(low * sizeof(int));
    while(x < nums1Size && y < nums2Size){
        if(nums1[x] == nums2[y]){
        nums3[z] = nums1[x];
            ++z;
            ++x;
            ++y; 
        }
        else { 
        (nums1[x] > nums2[y]) ?++y :++x;
       }
        
    }
    nums3 = (int*)realloc(nums3,z * sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = z;
    return nums3;
    }
```

Quicksort that solved the error:

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b){
    /* to prevent overflow */
    if(*(int *)a > *(int *)b) return 1;
    else if(*(int *)a < *(int *)b) return -1;
    return 0;
}


int *ret = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = 0;
    qsort(nums1, nums1Size, sizeof(int), comp);
    qsort(nums2, nums2Size, sizeof(int), comp);
```

Comment: Question is why i  get runtime / overflow error, code supposed to find the  intersection of  two arrays,  it does do find  intersection of two  arrays but in some cases it gives me a runtime  error  message on leetcode. I have found that my insertion sort causes this problem and it may be solved with using  pointers but  i  am not sure why using pointers solves my problem(pointers to array in sorting algorithm).

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? Also, the error would be helpful.

Comment: I edited the error on the message, i found the  error but i need the logic behind it

Comment: `i found the error but i need the logic behind it` if you found the error how you cannot know the reason ?

Comment: i found where the error was by doing some tests, i fixed the error with changing the sorting algorithm to another one. Why should i know what the problem was with the other sorting algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> while(c < nums1[j] && j >= 0){
> ```

must be

```
while(j >= 0 && c < nums1[j]) {
```

and

> ```
> while(c < nums2[j] && j >= 0){
> ```

must be

```
while(j >= 0 && c < nums2[j]) {
```

else you can have access before the arrays

> the solution to the problem may be using pointers with the sorting algorithm

if you do something similar and have pointers pointing before the arrays the behavior will be the same.

If you use indexes make them valid, if you use pointers make them valid too

---

Out of that

1. are you sure you are allowed to modify (sort) the input arrays ?
2. if numbers are present several times in the two arrays they are also present several times in the result, for me numbers must be present only one time in the result array

Answer (score 1):

```
while(c < nums1[j] && j >= 0)
```

The two parts of the conjunction are done in the wrong order.

If `j == -1`, then checking for `j >= 0` is too late, as you have already accessed `nums1[-1]`.

Answer (score -3):

Don't use `malloc(), calloc(), realloc()` in online compiler.

Using pointer in online compiler causes that run time error.

Comment: No, they are not in this case, i've said that problem is about my sort algorithm. I tested it out already.

Comment: This answer is implausible and not does not reflect my and others' actual experience.  The OP's error appears to arise from incorrect memory accesses -- that is, buggy code -- not from some unusual general limitation on programs' usage of standard library functions.  But it is possible that some online services do a better job at *noticing* such issues than you are used to.  That would serve their interests in providing a stable service.

Comment: I have used malloc in online compilers without problem

Comment: Your answer A. is not true and B. does not answer the question. Using `malloc()` or pointers in online compilers is no problem. I suggest you to delete it.